# How to pass an external parameter to objects created by SimpleXML

Tags: java, simple-framework

I'm de-serializing my config directly into object hierarchy. Some objects have constructor parameters which are not mentioned in the config like internal interfaces.

E.g. config file:

```
<config>
    <strategy param="value" class="MyStrategy">
</config>
```

classes:

```
class Config
{
    @ElementList(inline=true,entry="strategy")
    List<Object> strategies;
}

class MyStrategy
{
    MyStrategy(IFramework framework)
    {
    }
}
```

Here I have an instance of IFramework and would like SimpleXML to use it whenever an object needs IFramework parameter in a constructor. I haven't found a way to make the above work just by configuring SimpleXML.

The way I implemented it now is ugly. I read all  elements from xml nodes myself, create instances of strategy classes and call Persister.read() on created objects. In order to make it work I had to declare Config class with strict=false to skip strategies from being de-serialized by Simple and add a dummy "class" attribute to every strategy.

```
@Root(strict=false)
class Config
{
    List<Object> strategies;

    void loadStrategies(IFramework framework, Persister persister, InputNode source)
    {
        // traverse all nodes looking for "strategy"
        // create strategy (e.g. MyStrategy)
        // call persister.read(strategy, source)
    }
}

class MyStrategy
{
    @Attribute(name="class")
    String dummy;

    MyStrategy(IFramework framework)
    {
    }
}
```

I wonder if this could be solved by some mechanism in SimpleXML.
**Is it possible to tell SimpleXML to 'autowire' the IFramework instance to objects it creates?**

Answer (score 0):

Try and use a Converter, you can just create one and register it. It can then be called when ever you want to load the MyStrategy. See

http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/javadoc/org/simpleframework/xml/convert/RegistryStrategy.html